# Python mysqlclient connection fails with TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3 configured on MariaDB server

Tags: python, ssl, mariadb

I'm  not sure if what I'm seeing is a bug or some other configuration issue. With MariaDB 10.4.8, when I configure the `tls_version` option

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/ssltls-system-variables/#tls_version

without TLSv1.1 (i.e. TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3), the Python mysqlclient connection being used with Django fails. If I configure MariaDB back to including TLSv1.1, it starts working again without any other changes.

Is mysqlclient that far back on supporting new TLS versions? I don't see anything indicating the versions of TLS that are supported by mysqlclient.

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.3

OpenSSL 1.1.1d

mysqlclient 1.4.4

python 3.7.5

Django 2.2 (using the mysqlclient above in virtual environment)

Comment: What your OS, its version and the SSL lib incl. version?

Comment: updated with software versions...everything is "latest" as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mysqlclient (1.4.4.) uses libmysql which was built with yassl support instead of OpenSSL.

Yassl is discontinued (successor is WolfSSL) and doesn't support TLSv1.2 or newer. The client hello packet sends the highest supported TLS version to the server which is TLSv1.1 (3.1), since the server was configured to support TLSv1.2 (3.2) and TLSv1.3 (3.3) only an error will be returned, since there can't be an agreement on protocol version.

For this reason we only disabled TLSv1.0 in server, but not TLSv1.1 so clients built with yassl will still be able to connect to MariaDB 10.4.

. See also [MDEV-12190](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12190), [MDEV14101](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14101)

To fix this you will need to build libmysql with OpenSSL support or install libmysql from MySQL 8.0 which replaced Yassl by WolfSSL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still new to navigating various dependency and build limitations, but what you wrote makes sense. Given the use of Django, I'm surprised no one seemed to dig this out earlier. Are there still few people that are trying to use MariaDB with SSL, and restricting it to TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3? If people are using unix sockets on localhost, I guess this detail is moot.

Comment: Using TLS with MariaDB is quite common, especially if client and server are not one the same machine or within same trusted network. Restricting to TLS1.2 or 1.3 should be only done, if you can guarantee that all clients will support TLSv1.2. TLSv1.3 is even more restrictive, MariaDB client library (MariaDB Connector/C) for example doesn't support TLSv1.3 on Windows, since it is not supported yet by the underlying Windows native schannel library. Another side effect is that TLSv1.3 has it's own cipher suites, cipher suites from previous versions aren't supported anymore.

Comment: Right, when I was digging I learned a few more things about TLSv1.3. Thanks for the help!